# How to navigate to html id with [routerLink]

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to navigate to html id with `[routerLink]`

**blog.ts**:

```
tabsOverview: any = [
    {title: 'How to create project', url: 'create-project', id: 'create-project'},
    {title: 'How to invite collaborators', url: 'create-project', id: 'invite-collaborator'},
    {title: 'Manage subscription', url: 'create-project', id: 'manage-subscription'}
];
```

**blog.html**:

```
<li *ngFor="let tab of tabsOverview">
   <a class="list-group-item border-0" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[tab.url]">{{tab.title}}</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: change your code to `[routerLink]="tab.url"`

Answer (score 2):

Try to write without square brackets `[]` like that:

```
<a class="list-group-item border-0" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="tab.url">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[]` from the `tab.url`.

Just this `[routerLink]="tab.url"`.

Explanation: when you write something in `[]`, Angular expects an input, and the input you are providing with that code is an Array. The problem is that `routerlink` is expecting a string.